# Validate string as Proper Base64String and Convert to byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to validate if an input string is valid Base64 or not. If it's valid then convert into byte[].

I tried the following solutions

1. `RegEx`
2. `MemoryStream`
3. `Convert.FromBase64String`

For example I want to validate if `"932rnqia38y2"` is a valid Base64 string or not and then convert it to `byte[]`. This string is not valid Base64 but I'm always getting true or valid in my code.

please let me know if you have any solutions.

**Code**

```
//Regex _rx = new Regex(@"^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=|[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==)?$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Regex _rx = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
if (image == null) return null;

if ((image.Length % 4 == 0) && _rx.IsMatch(image))
{
    try
    {
        //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image));
        return Convert.FromBase64String(image);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: 932rnqia38y2 looks valid to me. simply call FromBase64String and catch the potential Exception should be sufficient.

Comment: I don't think you can check if a string can be interpreted as Base-64 using regular expressions. In any case, the string you are trying to validate *is* valid, so it's not surprising that you get true. Whether the data *in* the string is valid is an entirely different concern.

Answer (score 6):

Just create some helper, which will catch FormatException on input string:

```
    public static bool TryGetFromBase64String(string input, out byte[] output)
    {
        output = null;
        try
        {
            output = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```